# How to keep the selected data in the select combo after the query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function that allows me to select a category (from a select combo) to associate with a product while I'm creating it. It works well but when I modify the product, I would like that the category assigned during creation,  remain selected and visible at the beginning of the combo.

I suppose that i have to change something into the function when i update the product.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Function:

```
function CategoryTree(&$output=null, $cat_parent_id=0, $indent=null){

    global $con;

    try {

    // prepare select query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_parent_id=:parentid AND cat_lang = '{$_SESSION['lang']}'";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    // this is the first question mark
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $id);

    // execute our query
    $stmt->execute(array( 'parentid' => $cat_parent_id));

    while($c = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $disable= "";
        if($cat_parent_id==0 ){
          $disable= 'disabled="disabled" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;font-style:oblique"';
    }
    $output .= '<option  '. $disable.'  value=' . $c['cat_id'] . '>' . $indent . $c['cat_name'] . "</option>\n";
    if($c['cat_id'] != $cat_parent_id){

        CategoryTree($output, $c['cat_id'], $indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }
}
    // return the list of categories
    return $output;
}
// show error
catch(PDOException $exception){
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category" required />
   <option value="">Select a category</option>

<?php

    echo CategoryTree();
?>   
    </select>
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't get the point, because, after the user have selected an option from that category dropdown, it *will* keep selected... that's the normal behavior to any `<select>` HTML element, right?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Hi, In the query I only pass the value of the sessions. Is $ _SESSION also vulnerable to sql injection?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need (if I have understood your problem correctly) is to make use of the `'selected'` attribute of the option you can say which option is marked as selected when the page loads by saying

```
'<option  '. $disable.'  value=' . $c['cat_id'] . ' selected>'
```

(https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

You can then use the value in the `$_POST['category']` when the form is submitted and compare it to the category value (`$c['cat_id']`) in the loop to decide which element is selected.

When the form is submitted and the page reloaded then the last selected value will remain selected.

Forgive me if I haven't understood your question properly, but I THINK this is what you mean

Comment: I certainly didn't explain myself well. I'm sorry. I wanted to say that the function above is used to CREATE the product and that's okay, 
but, is it possible to have the same function that works both for CREATE and UPDATE? What is the difference? 
When i edit the product (already created) i need to show into the combo box, the category choosen in create step. Or i need to have a new function?

Comment: sorry @Ogum I don't really understand.  Perhaps edit your question with example output for what you get vs what you want.  Also could you clarify what you mean by create (I assumed you are talking about creating a database entry but can't see any create or update queries).  Try re-writing the question with a bit more specific detail and I'm sure someone will be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll rewrite my question here, since I can't explain myself. I have to rewrite this code from the old mysql_ to PDO.
Perhaps by writing code directly it is better understood.

The main function:

```
/*
    Generate combo box options containing the categories we have.
    if $catId is set then that category is selected
*/
function buildCategoryOptions($catId = 0)
{
    $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_parent_id, cat_name
            FROM tbl_category  WHERE cat_lang = '{$_SESSION['lang']}'
            ORDER BY cat_id";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);

    $categories = array();
    while($row = dbFetchArray($result)) {
        list($id, $parentId, $name) = $row;

        if ($parentId == 0) {
            // we create a new array for each top level categories
            $categories[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'children' => array());
        } else {
            // the child categories are put int the parent category's array
            $categories[$parentId]['children'][] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name); 
        }
    }   

    // build combo box options
    $list = '';
    foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
        $name     = $value['name'];
        $children = $value['children'];

        $list .= "<optgroup label=\"$name\">"; 

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $list .= "<option value=\"{$child['id']}\"";
            if ($child['id'] == $catId) {
                $list.= " selected";
            }

            $list .= ">{$child['name']}</option>\r\n";
        }

        $list .= "</optgroup>";
    }

    return $list;
}
```

**Create.php:**

```
$catId = (isset($_GET['catId']) && $_GET['catId'] > 0) ? $_GET['catId'] : 0;
$categoryList = buildCategoryOptions($catId);
```

and then

```
<select name="cboCategory" id="cboCategory" class="width-50">
     <option value="" selected>-- Choose Category --</option>
<?php
echo $categoryList;
?>   
  </select>
```

**update.php**

```
// get category list
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_parent_id, cat_name
        FROM tbl_category 
          ORDER BY cat_id";
$result = dbQuery($sql) or die('Cannot get Product. ' . mysql_error());

$categories = array();
while($row = dbFetchArray($result)) {
    list($id, $parentId, $name) = $row;

    if ($parentId == 0) {
        $categories[$id] = array('name' => $name, 'children' => array());
    } else {
        $categories[$parentId]['children'][] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name); 
    }
}   
// build combo box options
$list = '';
foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
    $name     = $value['name'];
    $children = $value['children'];

    $list .= "<optgroup label=\"$name\">"; 

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $list .= "<option value=\"{$child['id']}\"";

        if ($child['id'] == $cat_id) {
            $list .= " selected";
        }
        $list .= ">{$child['name']}</option>";
    }

    $list .= "</optgroup>";
}
?>
```

and then

```
<select name="cboCategory" id="cboCategory" class="box">
     <option value="" selected>-- Choose Category --</option>
<?php
    echo $list;
?>   
    </select>
```

The functions are:

```
 dbQuery() =    global $dbConn;

  $result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbConn));

    return $result;

dbFetchArray = function dbFetchArray($result, $resultType = MYSQL_NUM) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result, $resultType);
}
```